# The audience can suspend their disbelief ...?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The audience can suspend their disbelief ...?
Can you fill in the blank for me?
I want to convey that the audience's suspension of disbelief has limits but I forgot how to say it in the context of the sentence above .
I think it's"suspend their disbelief for so long".is it correct?

Comment: "The audience can suspend their disbelief for _only_ so long"

Comment: Or "The audience can _only_ suspend their disbelief for so long".

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase it as:

> The audience can only suspend their disbelief for so long

Less colloquially there is this:

> The audience can suspend their disbelief for only so long

Both of these sentences imply that there is a time element to the matter of the suspension of disbelief.

Going slightly further away from your original construction:

> The audience's suspension of disbelief can only take so much abuse.

This removes the time implication from the previous sentences.